# insert in sql with mysqli and cookie in php

Tags: php, cookies, mysqli

I have two files: Studio.php and Principale.php

In the first one i want insert in my database some values and add them also in a table of Principale.php

With the first row of the table in Principale.php and the first add in the table of my database it works, after no.

I thought to use a for loop to create more rows in the table of Principale.php

It shows me also this error : Notice: Undefined index: titolo1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Progetto\Principale.php on line 47

I think $res2 return a value different than TRUE but i don't know why.

Code of Principale.php :

```
$n=$_COOKIE['idstudio'];

for ($i=1;$i<$n;$i++) {
    echo "<table style='border: 1px solid black; margin-left:auto; margin- 
right:auto;'><caption> <p>Esperienze di Studio</p>
</caption> <thead style='color:green;'> <tr>";
    echo "<th style='border: 1px solid black;'> Titolo </th><th 
style='border: 1px solid black;'> Anno </th><th style='border: 1px solid 
black;'> Luogo </th> ";
    echo "</tr> </thead> <tbody style='color:blue'> <tr>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$_COOKIE["titolo$i"]." 
</td>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$_COOKIE["anno$i"]."</td>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$_COOKIE["luogo$i"]." 
</td>";
    echo "</tr></tbody</table><br><br>";
    }
echo "</div>";
```

Code of Studio.php :

```
$luogo = $_POST["luogo"];
$anno = $_POST["anno"];
$titolo = $_POST["titolo"];

$sql6="SELECT education_experience_id FROM education_experience ORDER BY 
education_experience_id DESC LIMIT 1;";
$result2=mysqli_query($connessione,$sql6);
$row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQLI_NUM);
$last_id2=$row2[0];
$id2 = $last_id2+1;

$eeid=$_COOKIE['id'];

$sql9="INSERT into EDUCATION_EXPERIENCE 
    (education_experience_id,title,year,place,user_id) VALUES                 
    ('$id2','$titolo','$anno','$luogo','$eeid')";
$res2=mysqli_query($connessione,$sql9);
echo "<br>";
mysqli_error($connessione);
if($res2 ==TRUE)   {
    setcookie("luogo$id2", $luogo, strtotime("+1 month"));
    setcookie("anno$id2", $anno, strtotime("+1 month"));
    setcookie("titolo$id2", $titolo, strtotime("+1 month"));
    setcookie("idstudio",$id2,strtotime("+1 month"));

    header("Location: Principale.php");
}
else
{
    echo "Impossibile aggiungere Esperienza<br>";
    echo "<a href='Principale.php'>Clicca Qui</a> per tornare alla pagina 
        principale.";
}
```

Comment: `Principale.php` expects cookies for `titolo1` through `titoloN`, but `Studio.php` only sets a cookie for `titoloN`.

Comment: Why? $id2 is a number that increment everytime i do an insert.

Comment: If user1 inserts a row, user2 won't get that cookie.

Comment: However $res2 do not value TRUE i think because it prints me the else when i add the second insert.

Comment: What does `echo mysqli_error($connessione);` show?

Comment: How can i solve it? I have to create a table with all the rows inserted.

Comment: mysqli_error doesn't show anything

Comment: You forgot to put `echo` before it in your code.

Comment: BTW, why are you incrementing the ID yourself, instead of using `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: Don't put all the data in cookies. `Principale.php` should query the database and display the table from there.

Comment: Duplicate entry '7' for key 'PRIMARY' and 7 is the last id that i pass with $eeid=$_COOKIE['id'];

Comment: I found a mistake in the insert query, ; missing at the end, but it always doesn't return true.

Comment: If two users run the script at the same time, they'll both get the same `$id2`, and try to insert the same `education_experience_id` into the table. You have to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` or transactions to prevent this.

Comment: You don't need `;` at the end.